# Translate enumerized value in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, internationalization

I need to translate enumerized value:

```
#ad.rb
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :price_currency, in: {:UAH => 0, :USD => 1}
end

#en.yml
ads:
    price_currency:
      UAH: "UAH"
      USD: "USD"
enumerize:
  ad:
    price_currency:
      UAH: "UAH"
      USD: "USD"
```

It translates well in simple form select input but does not in regular HTML layout:

```
%p= ad.price + ' ' + ad.price_currency.to_s if not ad.price.blank?
```

When I try to translate it the following way:

```
%p= ad.price + ' ' + t('ads.price_currency.' + ad.price_currency.to_s) if not ad.price.blank?
```

I receive the following error:

> no implicit conversion of Hash into String

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ok, the issue was not with enumerize but trying to translate empty value if price_currency did not exist.
fixed by adding validation of both price and price_currency:

```
%p= ad.price + ' ' + ad.price_currency.text if ad.price and ad.price_currency
```